# Need Regex to capture Specific Unknown String in txt file in Java

Tags: java, android, regex

I m not so good with Regex (Android or java) , so i need someone to tell how i can retrieve those string pattern in my file . thanks in advance.. I just need a pattern for those strings . 
I first try to search VOICE_REGISTRATION_STATE and then use a pattern to get all the following strings (from { to }) in the following expression.

```
VOICE_REGISTRATION_STATE {1, 271c, 0000058d, 16, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null}
```

for the second expression which is `(SignalStrength: 29 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 -1 2147483647 gsm|lte 0x4))` , i want to get the first string `(29)` after `SignalStrength :` which i can search in file.

finally, i also want to get carrier unknown value, i means the value in brackets in  the expression `carrier=[60501]` in my file .

I precise that i m not very good at english , so try to understand what i say and thanks in advance .

Comment: ask a single question.

Answer (score 1):

That to me looks like an array, which should already be split for you.

```
String[] VOICE_REGISTRATION_STATE = {"1", "271c", "0000058d", "16", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null};

String part1 = VOICE_REGISTRATION_STATE[0]; // "1"
String part2 = VOICE_REGISTRATION_STATE[1]; // "271c"
```

If this is the case there is no need to use anything like a regex as you are using a simple array. But as I'm not sure where you're getting this VOICE_REGISTRATION_STATE from I can't be sure what it returns

Comment: thanks , but in my file VOICE_REGISTRATION_STATE= {} is not recognised as array just as string ... To be Clear , the expression  is in a raw file .txt so it is not an array , just an expression ... Help me , i know i need a regex to do it and i precise that i can seek for VOICE_REGISTRATION_STATE which i know and then get the value which i don't know

Comment: Would you be able to provide the raw file and the code you're currently using to import it. I'll take a look at it and try to update my answer to help you.

Comment: this is somehow the file content :   01-21 10:53:03.911 D/DCT     ( 2785): overall state is IDLE

01-21 10:53:03.986 D/RILJ    ( 2785): [rild] [2050]< OPERATOR {xx,xx,xx,xx}

01-21 10:53:03.991 D/RILJ    ( 2785): [rild] [2051]< DATA_REGISTRATION_STATE {1, 271c, 0000058d, 2, null, 4}

01-21 10:53:03.991 D/PHONE   ( 2785): [ServiceState] setDataRegState=0

01-21 10:53:03.991 D/PHONE   ( 2785): [ServiceState] setDataRadioTechnology=2

Comment: I'm still not clear on what is actually generating that file. You may want to add the contents of the file to your question so I can see the full content